# Every time on token refresh is called when the application is launched

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**on token refresh call only when**

App deletes Instance ID

App is restored on a new device

User uninstalls/reinstall the app

User clears app data

**but On token refresh every time call when the app is Launched.**

**how can we one time call token refresh event when the app is installed?**

any solution of that problem?

```
MyFirebaseIIDService :

    [Service]

    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]

    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService 
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
           var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
           Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);            
        }
    }


AndriodMainfest.Xaml:

<application android:label="FirebasePushSample.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

     <receiver 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
        android:exported="false" />
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
   <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, I think there are other reasons caused your problem. Have you called `DeleteInstanceId()` in your code? Could provide a demo project?

Comment: no i don't called the DeleteInstanceId() .